# Send blob via websocket cause page reload

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, webrtc

I'm trying to send recordRTC blob via websocket to my Java server, my goal is to build a video stream service.

However, when the server received the blob, and write file, the web page would refresh, cause recordRTC stopped and socket disconnct.

Used package

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is my code.

Server side

```java
public void onMessage( WebSocket conn, ByteBuffer message ) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[message.remaining()];
    message.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    if(bytes.length > 0) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        UUID uuid  =  UUID.randomUUID();
        String id=uuid.toString();
        String filename =id.replace("-", "");
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(
                            new File("./uploads/"+filename +".webm")));
            bos.write(bytes);
            bos.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side

```js
function startCapture() {
    logElem.innerHTML = "";
    try {
        videoElem.srcObject = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions).then(
            (stream)=>{
                console.log(stream);
                recordRTC = RecordRTC(stream);
                recordRTC.startRecording();
                // blob segment and send every 3 second
                recording = setInterval(()=>{
                    recordRTC.stopRecording(()=>{
                            console.log("BLOB : ", recordRTC.getBlob());
                            recordRTC.getBlob().arrayBuffer().then((val)=>{
                                console.log("BLOB : ", recordRTC.getBlob());
                                socket.send(val);
                            });
                    })
                    recordRTC.startRecording();
                }, 3000);
                videoElem.srcObject = new MediaStream(stream);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: " + err);
    }
}
```

[reload event picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBhSX.jpg)

I found the reload EVENT occur after the fisrt blob sent and write to file, but I don't know why the event happend.

If server don't write blob to file, just receive it, the websocket and web would work perfectly without reloading.

How could I solve the reload EVENT problem?
Thanks

Comment: What line of the websocket code server side sends the reload event?